# SQL Server: how do I show placeholder rows from a case statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

If I have a table of data about people's ages such as:

```
Name    |    Age
--------+-----------
John    |    35
Mike    |    45
```

And I need to group by and output this data into a standard table such as:

```
Grouper  |    Count
---------+-------------
Under 50 |      2
Over 50  |      0
```

I am running a query similar to this (typed up quickly, may not work in real life. Illustrating a situation where I am using a `case` statement to create groups):

```
select
    case
       when Age <= 50 then 'Under 50'
       else 'Over 50'
    end as 'Grouper',
    count(Age) as 'Count'
from 
    theTable
group by 
    'Grouper'
```

I get an answer like this since there are no people over 50 in the table:

```
Grouper  |    Count
---------+-------------
Under 50 |      2
```

How can I force my results to keep every value in the case statement, even if there are no values found for it in the table?  I am not able to insert or modify any data or tables, this would be strictly for reporting purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would phrase this as:

```
select v.grouper, count(Age) as 'Count'
From (values ('Under 50', 0, 51), ('Over 50', 51, null)) v(grouper, lo, hi) left join
     theTable t
     on t.age >= v.lo and
        (t.age < v.hi or v.hi is null)
Group by grouper;
```

This generates something like a temporary lookup table with the age ranges and string that you want to include.  The important part -- from your perspective -- is the `left join`.  That keeps all the age ranges.

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNION`, as in:

```
select
  'Under 50' as grouper,
  sum(case when age <= 50 then 1 end) as count
from theTable
union
select
  'Over 50' as grouper,
  sum(case when age > 50 then 1 end) as count
from theTable
```